# I get memory leak when I execute CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I am wondering why I am receiving memory leak in case when `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` is called. Is it possible because it is debug build ? Or it is connected with wrong usage of the apple API?

```
public static func register(from url: URL) throws {
    guard let fontDataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: url as CFURL) else {
        throw RegisterFontError(errorMessage: "Could not create font data provider for \(url).")
    }
    
    let font = CGFont(fontDataProvider)
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error) else {
        throw error!.takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```

Apple Instruments :

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After investigation of the parameters of the `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` I found that `error` parameter is type of `UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>?`. And the main issue is connected with `Unmanaged` type.

So what is `Unmanaged` type.

> An Unmanaged wrapper, like an Optional wrapper, provides a layer of
>   safety between your code and a potentially nasty crash.  The
>   Unmanaged type stores a pointer whose memory is not controlled by
>   the Swift runtime system. Before using this data, you take
>   responsibility for how this memory should stay alive.

And what is `UnsafeMutablePointer`

> UnsafeMutablePointer provides no automated memory management or
>   alignment guarantees. You are responsible for handling the life cycle
>   of any memory you work with through unsafe pointers to avoid leaks or
>   undefined behavior.

So as it possible to understand we should fix my code with this few code lines.That will release `error` after we fetch error description.

```
   public static func register(from url: URL) throws {
        guard let fontDataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: url as CFURL) else {
            throw RegisterFontError(errorMessage: "Could not create font data provider for \(url).")
        }

        let font = CGFont(fontDataProvider)

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error) else {
            let message = error.debugDescription
            error?.release()
            throw RegisterFontError.init(errorMessage: message)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Oleg Gordiichuk you're a lifesaver :) thanks