# Custom CGFonts never deallocated when scrolling TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am having an issue with `CGFont` not being deallocated when used within a TableView, minimal example of what I'm trying to do is at follow:

```
extension FontPickerPageViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        fontItems.count
    }

    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: FontPickerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
            for: IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0)
        ) as! FontPickerCollectionViewCell

        let fontItem = fontItems[indexPath.item]
        let name = fontItem.family

        cell.label.text = name

        if let font = try? fontManager.getFont(forName: name) {
            cell.label.font = font
        } else if let fontFile = fontItem.files.first(where: { $0.variant == .regular }),
                  let url = URL(string: fontFile.urlString)
        {
            // Download font
            Task {
                do {
                    let data = try await NetworkManager.downloadData(URLRequest(url: url))
                    try await fontManager.registerFont(for: data, name: name)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

And the font manager:

```
final class FontManager {

    enum FontManager2Error: LocalizedError {
        case registerProviderError
        case postScriptNameError
        case fontNotFound

        var errorDescription: String? {
            switch self {
            case .registerProviderError:
                return "Failed to register font with provider"
            case .postScriptNameError:
                return "Failed to get the post script name"
            case .fontNotFound:
                return "Failed to find font"
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Proprties

    static let shared = FontManager()


    private var storage = [String: String]() //fontName : other name
    private let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "lock", attributes: .concurrent)

    // MARK: - Initializers

    private init() {}

    // MARK: - Font Management

    private func registerFont(for data: Data, name: String, completion: @escaping (Result<(), Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let provider = CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData),
              let cgFont = CGFont(provider)
        else {
            return completion(.failure(FontManager2Error.registerProviderError))
        }

        guard let postScriptName = cgFont.postScriptName as? String else {
            return completion(.failure(FontManager2Error.postScriptNameError))
        }

        CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(cgFont, nil)
        lockQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            self?.storage[name] = postScriptName
            completion(.success(()))
        }
    }

    func registerFont(for data: Data, name: String) async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            registerFont(for: data, name: name) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    continuation.resume()
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func isFontRegistered(name: String) -> Bool {
        lockQueue.sync {
            storage[name] != nil
        }
    }

    func getFont(forName name: String) throws -> UIFont {
        try lockQueue.sync {
            guard let postScriptName = storage[name],
                  let uiFont = UIFont(name: postScriptName, size: Config.defaultFontSize)
            else {
                throw FontManager2Error.fontNotFound
            }

            return uiFont
        }
    }

}
```

I attempt to retrieve the `UIFont` from the `FontManager`, if it doesn't exist then I download the font data and register it in the `FontManager`. Note that in this minimal example font won't update until the table has been scrolled several times.

The new fonts are set correctly however when I inspect Debug Memory graph I can see there are around 400 `CGFont` objects in the memory, this corresponds to the total number of fonts I have loaded.

Why are all the fonts in the memory and not just the ones for the displayed table cells? If I use `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)` for the fonts instead of a custom font then there will only be around 33 `CGFont` objects at a time in the memory which corresponds to the number of cells displayed on the screen. What am I missing here?

Comment: How big can these objects be? My initial feeling is that you should just not worry about it. But see also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376991/ios-swift-5-auto-release-coretext-coregraphics-memory, maybe you have to do manual memory management on these puppies.

Comment: I'm loading around 400 fonts and the total memory usage is 242mb versus 90mb without custom fonts. @matt

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364620/i-get-memory-leak-when-i-execute-ctfontmanagerregistergraphicsfont

Comment: Doesn't seem related, in that question it's not released because of an error object, I'm not using an error object.

Comment: Nevertheless it does show you have to do memory management that you aren't doing.

Comment: Memory management on what object?

Comment: Around registration. I think if you comment out the registration the problem will go away.

Comment: The font needs to be registered so it can be init via name